# Outlook Taskboard JavaScript / HTML

Tags: javascript, html, outlook, kanban

there are different taskboards for Outlook and I have been using the taskboard from https://github.com/evrenvarol/outlook-taskboard

There is another taskboard from janvanveldhuizen and the percent for the task is shown on this taskboard.
https://github.com/janvanveldhuizen/janban

How can I add this function to my task board?

I found the following code in the JS file, but I don't know where exactly I have to enter it and how I link the code with the HTML.

app.js

```
    var getTasksFromOutlook = function (path, sort, folderStatus) {
        try {
            var i, array = [];
            var tasks = getTaskItems(path);

            var count = tasks.Count;
            for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                var task = tasks(i);
                if (task.Status == folderStatus || folderStatus == -1) {
                    array.push({
                        entryID: task.EntryID,
                        subject: task.Subject,
                        priority: task.Importance,
                        startdate: new Date(task.StartDate),
                        duedate: new Date(task.DueDate),
                        sensitivity: task.Sensitivity,
                        categories: getCategoryStyles(task.Categories),
                        notes: taskBodyNotes(task.Body, $scope.config.TASKNOTE_MAXLEN),
                        status: taskStatusText(task.Status),
                        oneNoteTaskID: getUserProperty(tasks(i), "OneNoteTaskID"),
                        oneNoteURL: getUserProperty(tasks(i), "OneNoteURL"),
                        completeddate: new Date(task.DateCompleted),
                        **percent: task.PercentComplete,**
```

app.js for each column

```
    $scope.taskFolders[BACKLOG].displayPercent = $scope.config.BACKLOG_FOLDER.DISPLAY_PROPERTIES.PERCENT;
```

app.js for each column

```
     },
        "COMPLETED_FOLDER": {
            "TYPE": "DONE",
            "ACTIVE": true,
            "NAME": "Kanban",
            "TITLE": "COMPLETED",
            "LIMIT": 0,
            "SORT": "-completeddate,-priority,subject",
            "DISPLAY_PROPERTIES": {
                "OWNER": false,
                **"PERCENT": false,**
```

kanban.html

```
<div ng-if="( folder.displayPercent )" class="pull-right"> {{ task.percent }}%</div>
```

My problem is that the version of Janban is completely different, so I can't just copy and paste the code.

I'd be happy for help.

Thanks a lot, Marcus